# How to convert, replace string in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to match and replace  input data .
eg "from" to "to" as rule.This rule is taken from python converter.

**Rule .josn**

```
{"rules" = "[ { \"from\" : \"([\\u102D\\u102E\\u103D\\u102F\\u1037\\u1095])\\\\1+\", \"to\" : \"$1\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u200B\", \"to\": \"\" }, { \"from\" : \"\\u103d\\u103c\", \"to\" : \"\\u108a\" }, { \"from\": \"(\\u103d|\\u1087)\", \"to\": \"\\u103e\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u103c\", \"to\": \"\\u103d\" }, { \"from\": \"(\\u103b|\\u107e|\\u107f|\\u1080|\\u1081|\\u1082|\\u1083|\\u1084)\", \"to\": \"\\u103c\" }, { \"from\": \"(\\u103a|\\u107d)\", \"to\": \"\\u103b\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1039\", \"to\": \"\\u103a\" }, { \"from\": \"(\\u1066|\\u1067)\", \"to\": \"\\u1039\\u1006\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u106a\", \"to\": \"\\u1009\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u106b\", \"to\": \"\\u100a\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u106c\", \"to\": \"\\u1039\\u100b\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u106d\", \"to\": \"\\u1039\\u100c\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u106e\", \"to\": \"\\u100d\\u1039\\u100d\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u106f\", \"to\": \"\\u100d\\u1039\\u100e\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1070\", \"to\": \"\\u1039\\u100f\" }, { \"from\": \"(\\u1071|\\u1072)\", \"to\": \"\\u1039\\u1010\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1060\", \"to\": \"\\u1039\\u1000\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1061\", \"to\": \"\\u1039\\u1001\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1062\", \"to\": \"\\u1039\\u1002\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1063\", \"to\": \"\\u1039\\u1003\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1065\", \"to\": \"\\u1039\\u1005\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1068\", \"to\": \"\\u1039\\u1007\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1069\", \"to\": \"\\u1039\\u1008\" }, { \"from\": \"(\\u1073|\\u1074)\", \"to\": \"\\u1039\\u1011\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1075\", \"to\": \"\\u1039\\u1012\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1076\", \"to\": \"\\u1039\\u1013\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1077\", \"to\": \"\\u1039\\u1014\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1078\", \"to\": \"\\u1039\\u1015\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1079\", \"to\": \"\\u1039\\u1016\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u107a\", \"to\": \"\\u1039\\u1017\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u107c\", \"to\": \"\\u1039\\u1019\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1085\", \"to\": \"\\u1039\\u101c\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1033\", \"to\": \"\\u102f\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1034\", \"to\": \"\\u1030\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u103f\", \"to\": \"\\u1030\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1086\", \"to\": \"\\u103f\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1036\\u1088\", \"to\": \"\\u1088\\u1036\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1088\", \"to\": \"\\u103e\\u102f\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1089\", \"to\": \"\\u103e\\u1030\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u108a\", \"to\": \"\\u103d\\u103e\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u103B\\u1064\", \"to\": \"\\u1064\\u103B\" }, { \"from\": \"(\\u1031)?([\\u1000-\\u1021])\\u1064\", \"to\": \"\\u1004\\u103a\\u1039$1$2\" }, { \"from\": \"(\\u1031)?([\\u1000-\\u1021])(\\u103b)?\\u108b\", \"to\": \"\\u1004\\u103a\\u1039$1$2$3\\u102d\" }, { \"from\": \"(\\u1031)?([\\u1000-\\u1021])(\\u103b)?\\u108c\", \"to\": \"\\u1004\\u103a\\u1039$1$2$3\\u102e\" }, { \"from\": \"(\\u1031)?([\\u1000-\\u1021])\\u108d\", \"to\": \"\\u1004\\u103a\\u1039$1$2\\u1036\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u108e\", \"to\": \"\\u102d\\u1036\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u108f\", \"to\": \"\\u1014\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1090\", \"to\": \"\\u101b\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1091\", \"to\": \"\\u100f\\u1039\\u100d\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1092\", \"to\": \"\\u100b\\u1039\\u100c\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1019\\u102c(\\u107b|\\u1093)\", \"to\": \"\\u1019\\u1039\\u1018\\u102c\" }, { \"from\": \"(\\u107b|\\u1093)\", \"to\": \"\\u1039\\u1018\" }, { \"from\": \"(\\u1094|\\u1095)\", \"to\": \"\\u1037\" }, { \"from\": \"([\\u1000-\\u1021])\\u1037\\u1032\", \"to\": \"$1\\u1032\\u1037\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1096\", \"to\": \"\\u1039\\u1010\\u103d\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1097\", \"to\": \"\\u100b\\u1039\\u100b\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u103c([\\u1000-\\u1021])([\\u1000-\\u1021])?\", \"to\": \"$1\\u103c$2\" }, { \"from\": \"([\\u1000-\\u1021])\\u103c\\u103a\", \"to\": \"\\u103c$1\\u103a\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1047(?=[\\u102c-\\u1030\\u1032\\u1036-\\u1038\\u103d\\u1038])\", \"to\": \"\\u101b\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1031\\u1047\", \"to\": \"\\u1031\\u101b\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1040(\\u102e|\\u102f|\\u102d\\u102f|\\u1030|\\u1036|\\u103d|\\u103e)\", \"to\": \"\\u101d$1\" }, { \"from\": \"([^\\u1040\\u1041\\u1042\\u1043\\u1044\\u1045\\u1046\\u1047\\u1048\\u1049])\\u1040\\u102b\", \"to\": \"$1\\u101d\\u102b\" }, { \"from\": \"([\\u1040\\u1041\\u1042\\u1043\\u1044\\u1045\\u1046\\u1047\\u1048\\u1049])\\u1040\\u102b(?!\\u1038)\", \"to\": \"$1\\u101d\\u102b\" }, { \"from\": \"^\\u1040(?=\\u102b)\", \"to\": \"\\u101d\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1040\\u102d(?!\\u0020?/)\", \"to\": \"\\u101d\\u102d\" }, { \"from\": \"([^\\u1040-\\u1049])\\u1040([^\\u1040-\\u1049\\u0020]|[\\u104a\\u104b])\", \"to\": \"$1\\u101d$2\" }, { \"from\": \"([^\\u1040-\\u1049])\\u1040(?=[\\\\f\\\\n\\\\r])\", \"to\": \"$1\\u101d\" }, { \"from\": \"([^\\u1040-\\u1049])\\u1040$\", \"to\": \"$1\\u101d\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1031([\\u1000-\\u1021\\u103f])(\\u103e)?(\\u103b)?\", \"to\": \"$1$2$3\\u1031\" }, { \"from\": \"([\\u1000-\\u1021])\\u1031([\\u103b\\u103c\\u103d\\u103e]+)\", \"to\": \"$1$2\\u1031\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1032\\u103d\", \"to\": \"\\u103d\\u1032\" }, { \"from\": \"([\\u102d\\u102e])\\u103b\", \"to\": \"\\u103b$1\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u103d\\u103b\", \"to\": \"\\u103b\\u103d\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u103a\\u1037\", \"to\": \"\\u1037\\u103a\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u102f(\\u102d|\\u102e|\\u1036|\\u1037)\\u102f\", \"to\": \"\\u102f$1\" }, { \"from\": \"(\\u102f|\\u1030)(\\u102d|\\u102e)\", \"to\": \"$2$1\" }, { \"from\": \"(\\u103e)(\\u103b|\\u103c)\", \"to\": \"$2$1\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1025(?=[\\u1037]?[\\u103a\\u102c])\", \"to\": \"\\u1009\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1025\\u102e\", \"to\": \"\\u1026\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1005\\u103b\", \"to\": \"\\u1008\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1036(\\u102f|\\u1030)\", \"to\": \"$1\\u1036\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1031\\u1037\\u103e\", \"to\": \"\\u103e\\u1031\\u1037\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1031\\u103e\\u102c\", \"to\": \"\\u103e\\u1031\\u102c\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u105a\", \"to\": \"\\u102b\\u103a\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1031\\u103b\\u103e\", \"to\": \"\\u103b\\u103e\\u1031\" }, { \"from\": \"(\\u102d|\\u102e)(\\u103d|\\u103e)\", \"to\": \"$2$1\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u102c\\u1039([\\u1000-\\u1021])\", \"to\": \"\\u1039$1\\u102c\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1039\\u103c\\u103a\\u1039([\\u1000-\\u1021])\", \"to\": \"\\u103a\\u1039$1\\u103c\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u103c\\u1039([\\u1000-\\u1021])\", \"to\": \"\\u1039$1\\u103c\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1036\\u1039([\\u1000-\\u1021])\", \"to\": \"\\u1039$1\\u1036\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u104e\", \"to\": \"\\u104e\\u1004\\u103a\\u1038\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1040(\\u102b|\\u102c|\\u1036)\", \"to\": \"\\u101d$1\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1025\\u1039\", \"to\": \"\\u1009\\u1039\" }, { \"from\": \"([\\u1000-\\u1021])\\u103c\\u1031\\u103d\", \"to\": \"$1\\u103c\\u103d\\u1031\" }, { \"from\": \"([\\u1000-\\u1021])\\u103b\\u1031\\u103d(\\u103e)?\", \"to\": \"$1\\u103b\\u103d$2\\u1031\" }, { \"from\": \"([\\u1000-\\u1021])\\u103d\\u1031\\u103b\", \"to\": \"$1\\u103b\\u103d\\u1031\" }, { \"from\": \"([\\u1000-\\u1021])\\u1031(\\u1039[\\u1000-\\u1021])\", \"to\": \"$1$2\\u1031\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1038\\u103a\", \"to\": \"\\u103a\\u1038\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u102d\\u103a|\\u103a\\u102d\", \"to\": \"\\u102d\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u102d\\u102f\\u103a\", \"to\": \"\\u102d\\u102f\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u0020\\u1037\", \"to\": \"\\u1037\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1037\\u1036\", \"to\": \"\\u1036\\u1037\" }, { \"from\": \"[\\u102d]+\", \"to\": \"\\u102d\" }, { \"from\": \"[\\u103a]+\", \"to\": \"\\u103a\" }, { \"from\": \"[\\u103d]+\", \"to\": \"\\u103d\" }, { \"from\": \"[\\u1037]+\", \"to\": \"\\u1037\" }, { \"from\": \"[\\u102e]+\", \"to\": \"\\u102e\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u102d\\u102e|\\u102e\\u102d\", \"to\": \"\\u102e\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u102f\\u102d\", \"to\": \"\\u102d\\u102f\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1037\\u1037\", \"to\": \"\\u1037\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1032\\u1032\", \"to\": \"\\u1032\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1044\\u1004\\u103a\\u1038\", \"to\": \"\\u104E\\u1004\\u103a\\u1038\" }, { \"from\": \"([\\u102d\\u102e])\\u1039([\\u1000-\\u1021])\", \"to\": \"\\u1039$2$1\" }, { \"from\": \"(\\u103c\\u1031)\\u1039([\\u1000-\\u1021])\", \"to\": \"\\u1039$2$1\" }, { \"from\": \"\\u1036\\u103d\", \"to\": \"\\u103d\\u1036\" }]";}
```

I have no idea how to do that
The purpose is to replace non unicode input into unicode standard.Most people in my country use non unicode font .So.i need to replace their input into unicode with rule eg( rule.json).I tried like below .but it is not convert .

```
   String jsonString = await loadJsonFromAssets();
   final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
   RuleList rule = new RuleList.fromJson(jsonResponse);
   print('from :${rule.rules[0].from}');
   print('to :${rule.rules[0].to}');
   var ruleLength = rule.rules.length;

 for(var i=0;i< ruleLength;i++){
  print("Looping:${rule.rules[i].from}");
   String txt = "ေနေကာင္းလား";//non unicode starndard text
   if(txt.contains(rule.rules[i].from)){
     var  translatedTxt = txt.replaceAll(new 
 RegExp(rule.rules[i].from), rule.rules[i].to);
     print('tran:$translatedTxt');//match and replace with uniccode

   }else{
     print('not found');
   }

   }
 }
```

Comment: do you mean simply finding and replacing 'from' to 'to'. Something like this ?
rule.replaceAll('from','to'). 
replacing non unicode input into unicode something different. Check this 
http://www.shutongye.com/dartapi/dart-convert/Utf8Codec-class.html for those

Comment: ***I edited my questions*** plz.checks it again

Answer (score 0):

you should use replaceAll method https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html

```
final newReplacedString = rule.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'from'), 'to'); // 'résumé'
```

Comment: I tried that,but get what i want, now i edited my post.u can check and help solve